# Facebook как получить AdImage url из image_hash?

Tags: python, api, facebook, facebooksdk

Мой код `python-business-sdk`:

```py
account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
img = account.get_ad_images(params={'hashes': ['6b709f0275d0bdf18fb78ef08492ee79'})[0]
print(img['url'])  # doesnt work
primt(img[AdImage.Field.url])  # doesnt work
```

Я делаю реквест но получаю только `id` и `hash` в моей `img` переменной (которая является `AdImage`):

```py
'{..., _json': {'hash': '6b709f0275d0bdf18fb78ef08492ee79', 'id': '36246837:6b709f0275d0bdf18fb78ef08492ee79'}}}
```

Но мне нужен `url` изображения, тут документация где указаны поля, где и есть `url`, но он не приходит.. или я не знаю как его получить

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте в метод `fields=['url']`